# Is performing .ToList() more than once is a bad idea?

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, xamarin

I've written the below function to query the SQLite DB in my Xamarin forms app. But, since I have to call **.ToList()** twice, I'm not very confident about it. Is this bad code? Any feedback will be highly appreciated.

```
public static List<string> GetAllLocationIds()
    {
        try
        {
            lock (CollisionLock)
            {
               //TableQuery<TResult> First .ToList() result
               //List<string> Second .ToList() result
                return Database.Table<Location>().ToList().Select(loc=>loc.LocationId).ToList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Insights.Report(ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Performing .Select directly on  `Database.Table<Location>()` results in the following exception.`

```
System.MissingMethodException: Default constructor not found for type 
System.String at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceMono`
```

Comment: You may be able to avoid `ToList` completely in this method. Could you instead return `IEnumerable<string>` or `IQueryable<string>`? The caller may want to further refine the results. At the very least, the caller will likely need to enumerate the collection. If you avoid `ToList`, then it can be enumerated only once instead of multiple times.

Comment: People here are soooo keen to downvote without any explanation. Is this question not valid? Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can not do Linq projections to `string` types like that with `sqlite-net(-pcl)` as it needs a default parameterless constructor.

What follows is the "best way" simulate a "Linq projection" that I have found when Mobile memory and performance is considered.

1. Use a custom Class with only the columns that need projected
2. Use a SQL query with only the columns needed to map to that custom class (`where` filter in the select statement if needed)
3. Convert to custom type

#### Actual Table Class:

```
class Location
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Column1 { get; set; }
    public int Column2 { get; set; }
    ~~~
    public string LocationId { get; set; }
}
```

Now make a new class that describes your "projection" needs, in this case I only want the `LocationId` column.

#### Projection Class

```
class SimpleList
{
    public string LocationId { get; set; }
}
```

#### SQL Select (selecting only the columns that map to the projection class)

```
SQLiteConnection.Query<SimpleList>("select LocationId from [Location]")
```

Now you have a `List<SimpleList>`, you can convert it to a `List<string>` if you really need to:

```
SQLiteConnection.Query<SimpleList>("select LocationId from [Location]").ConvertAll(x => x.LocationId);
```

Is it worth it? If you have a ***large*** number of rows and/or columns in your table and **cannot** use a deferred query and/or avoid a Linq projection... IMHO yes... Use the profiler to confirm ;-)

If you have a couple dozen rows? Maybe not, but even then the number of temp. objects that get instanced is reduced, and for me that is a win on mobile.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to use an anonymous type instead? Like `.Select(loc => new { id = loc.Id }).ToList();`

Comment: wasn't aware of the [linked bug](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/408) . anonymous type has the same problem. so it's not an option

Comment: @woelliJ No, same issue, there is not default constructor and that just leads to `Default constructor not found for type <>f__AnonymousType0``1[[System.String,.....`

Comment: @woelliJ `sqlite-net(-pcl)` is a very light weight ORM on top of `SQLitePCLRaw` and it works great at what it does. You can go full-blown and use the MS Entity Framework for SQLite, but that is so heavy on mobile (memory and performance wise) that I tend to stay away from it...

Comment: a bit off topic: have you maybe tried EF Core SQLite and could say something about its performance / memory impact? I'm considering using it in a project

Comment: @woelliJ That was the framework (v1.1.2) that I was referring to. There are various issues with it on Xamarin, the big one for me is it is a really heavy framework in a resource restricted mobile environment and very recently was paid to stripped it out of an app due to memory and perf problems. Now on a server (or desktop app) where x10-x100 memory and cpu cycles are available, it is a great framework with great devs working on it.... but of course that is an opinion. *IF* you are targeting Xamarin mobile w/ it, profile it yourself using some real-life data on real-world low-end devices.

Comment: Finally I ended up using this. Maybe it's not the best approach but it's better that calling .ToList() twice. Thanks @SushiHangover !

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is.

On

```
Database.Table<Location>().ToList()
```

You are materializing all of Table `Location`. Then you are only selecting the `LocationId` in Memory.

Instead use:

```
Database.Table<Location>().Select(loc=>loc.LocationId).ToList();
```

Which is working directly on `IQueryable<Location>` and only materializes the `LocationId`. Assuming `Table<Location>` is `IQueryable<Location>`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I've already tried this. See the edited question.

Comment: Take a look at [this bug](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/408) @Heshan. (If that is the library you are using). `ToList` might be a workaround, but it is still not good for above statet reason. Maybe you could use another SqlLite-Linq-Provider.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @Christian. Yes, that's the library I'm using.

Comment: .Cast or any other method that works on IEnumerable should work instead of first ToList.